# custom tableHeaderView hide cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableheader

I'm trying to add a view to my tableview as a tableHeaderView. I drag a view from the interface builder and drop it into my tableview. The size of the header is a small, so I resize it by coding. When I run my app, it becomes like this:

**If I change background colour to white colour**[image]

**If I change background colour to clear idea**
[image]

Here is the code I change my tableview header size:

```
self.myTableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 290)
```

Any suggestion to fix it please!

Comment: you use tableview controller or you adding different subview in a view controller?

Comment: I used different subview in a view controller.

Comment: so you should add the "header" to a new subview at the top of the UI and adding table view at the bottom of the UI which is much better. That means don't put your "header" in the tableview.

Comment: But I want to make my header scrolled while tableview is scrolling.

Comment: ok, so did you `viewForHeaderInSection`??

Comment: nope. But why can't I just drag and drop it from IB?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113275/discussion-between-inuyasha-and-user2352577l).

Answer (score 2):

Use this UItableView extension.

I was having the same issue

```
extension UITableView {

    func setTableHeaderView(headerView: UIView?) {
        // set the headerView
        tableHeaderView = headerView

        // check if the passed view is nil
        guard let headerView = headerView else { return }

        // check if the tableHeaderView superview view is nil just to avoid
        // to use the force unwrapping later. In case it fail something really
        // wrong happened
        guard let tableHeaderViewSuperview = tableHeaderView?.superview else {
            assertionFailure("This should not be reached!")
            return
        }

        // force updated layout
        headerView.setNeedsLayout()
        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

        // set tableHeaderView width
        tableHeaderViewSuperview.addConstraint(headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHeaderViewSuperview.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0))

        // set tableHeaderView height
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        tableHeaderViewSuperview.addConstraint(headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height))
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a xib which holds the kind of `header view` you want to add it on `TableView`. Then load your xib in `viewWillAppear` method of the `controller` using `[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@""]` method. Now add that `NSBundle` returned view as `tableView` header by using, `tv.tableHeaderView = <your UI view>;`